# Waypoints Ai for turn base game

Tags: c#

[image]
(Picture of the game board)

I am trying to make an Waypoint system were Dracula will set a random destination for himself, he takes the shortest route and when he gets over there he sets himself a new random route. For example: Dracula starts in 
Le Havre, he sets him self a random destination to go to Prague, the shortest route is Brussels, Cologne, Frankfurt, Nuremberg then Prague. When he gets to Prague he then sets himself a new random destination to go to Bordeaux and so on. I have attempted to make it myself but because roads don't connect to each other and the pattern of the towns can't exactly be put into a grid form I have struggled to get it to work. If anyone could help me that would be much appreciated thank you

Comment: Seems like we might need a lot more details to give you any meaningful help.

Comment: Hmm.  Route optimization is its own separate and very broad topic.  Have you looked into A\* or other searching algorithms?

Comment: This is way too broad of a question. Look at [this how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: A* doesn't need a grid.  You can use it with arbitrary graphs- and it works especially well when you have sensible graphs embedded in the plane (where the Euclidean distance heuristic should still work) like yours.

Comment: Okay, thank you for wanting to help, to awnser the first question the main details I can give is I want the Dracula character to start so were randomly on the board as long as it's not the sea, then another random generator sets a place for Dracula to travel to, he then goes the shortest route to get there, when he reaches there the random generator then selects a new random place for him to travel to, he needs  only moves one space and to awnser e second question I have looked at a* but I found it really difficult to implement because of the in even nature of the board

Comment: I very much appreciate that you took the time to look at my question

Comment: Google for "pathfinding algorithms", there's plenty of them. If your graph is that simple, you may choose wave algorithm (Lee algorithm) as it is easily implemented and will probably suffice.

Comment: I am very appreciative of you helping me find the right algorithm, my main concern is I am having trouble tryin to implement it, I'm not sure how I would right out this algorithm in code

Comment: From your comments i gather that you are looking for someone to implement it for you?

Comment: I am just looking for some help, I dont know how to write this out, I just wanted to know how I would go about writing it out so I can do it myself. I am very great full for the help but if I don't know how to write out the algorithm then I'm just back at square one

Comment: I'm not looking for a hand out I just wanted some help and advice

Comment: Check out Eric Lippert's series of articles on A* (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/02/path-finding-using-a-in-c-3-0.aspx ).  It includes working code and solid explanations.  (Also read everything else by Lippert; he's a goldmine)

Comment: That's was actually very helpful thank you